# Parsing a string

Tags: c, string

I am implementing a program that accepts `g,a and x` as options . Called with the option `-g` it accepts the ID of employees and computers, it should then stores the ids in the `empl_id_array` and `comp_id_array`

Example of use:

```
 ./my_test -g e-1-2-3-c-0-1
 ./my_test -g e-1-2-c-0
```

The expected result from the 1st example is :

```
empl_id_array[] = {1,2,3} //e-1-2-3
comp_id_array[] = {0,1}  // c-0-1
```

The problem as you can see is that in the 1st example 3 employee IDs are passed in the 2nd 2 IDs are passed so I think I can't use `scanf` family to parse `optarg`(the format is variable).

What I have done is a function `get_resource` that do the parsing but it lacks a lot of checks. So I am asking if there is a function that better handles this situation, should I do this manually?

I take a look to `strtok` and regular expressions but they don't seem to resolve the problem, correct me if I am wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int empl_id_array[10];
int empl_id_array_count = 0;
int comp_id_array[10];
int comp_id_array_count = 0;

void get_resource(char *resource_str);

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int opt;
    char *pattern = "g:a:x:";
    char str[20];

    while ((opt = getopt(ac, av, pattern)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
          case 'g':
            strcpy(str, optarg);
            get_resource(str);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void get_resource(char *resource_str) {
    int i = 0;
    int exit = 0;
    int state = -1; /* (-1): initial state
                        (0): means we are actually reading an employee ID
                        (1): Actually getting computer ID
                        (2): End of the parsing */
    char car;

    while (!exit) {
        car = resource_str[i];
        if (car == '\0')
            state = 2; /* parsing finished */

        switch (state) {
          case -1:
            if (car == 'e')
                state = 0;
            if (car == 'c')
                state = 1;
            break;
          case 0:
            if (('0' <= car) && (car <= '9')) {
                empl_id_array[empl_id_array_count] = car - '0';
                empl_id_array_count++;
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            if (('0' <= car) && (car <= '9')) {
                comp_id_array[comp_id_array_count] = car - '0';
                comp_id_array_count++;
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            exit = 1;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, forget about `sscanf` (not `scanf`) for this problem.

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger, if you haven't done it before. With a debugger you can step through code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Doing that should give you a clear hint about the problem in just the second iteration of the `get_resource` loop.

Comment: First: use a debugger to find where your algorithm goes wrong. It will really help you to learn and develop. Second: no other choice to parse "manually" (ie without scanf) for this issue. Third: You never return to state "-1" to switch from computers list to employes list. Fourth: use enum or define to name your states instead of giving magic number

Comment: @MichaelWalz, `sscanf ` accepts a "static " format i guess, how can i use it in my case ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'am not sure to undrestand "the problem in just the second iteration" ? any way for sure there is a lot of problems. what i want to know should i do it manually like this ? no better solution ?

Comment: The first iteration of the loop you "read" the character `'e'` from the string, and handle it. The second iteration you will read the character `'-'` from the string, which is not handled anywhere. Is that on purpose? If it *is* on purpose, consider adding comments about it at the very least. And also you might want to read about [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Yes this is why I mention that there is a lot of checks missing, You're right i have to add this as comment

Comment: @sudoman : 1 and 2 and 3

Comment: computers IDs : 0 and 1

Comment: You need to build a little parser from the ground up, on top of pointer reads and increments (or array index incrementing). That's the point of this  exercise.

Comment: @Mouin as stated by other comments: you cannot use `sscanf` for this issue. You can only use it if you know the input format in advance, which is not the case here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'am reading this [tuto](http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml) and find this interesting format specifiier : `%{format%}`; it helps to repeateadely matche the format as much as possible(see also example in the end). I have used this `sscanf(resource_str,"e-%{%d-%}c%{-%d%}",empl_id_array,comp_id_array);`, but it's not working yet

Comment: In compilation I have a warning : `warning: unknown conversion type character ‘{’ in format [-Wformat=]` Any Idea?

Comment: @Mouin the compiler told you that `sscanf` does not support the `%{format%}` format specifier. The tutorial you are talking about is not about C but about [Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pike_(programming_language)). Just forget about `sscanf`, it's _not_ what you need here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I didn't pay attention to this Thanks.